# Linear regression on a multiindex dataframe

Tags: dataframe, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df1.index.name = 'time'

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df2.index.name = 'time'

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df3.index.name = 'time'

panel = pd.concat([df1.stack(),df2.stack(),df3.stack()],axis=1)
panel.columns = ['column1','column2','column3']
panel.index = panel.index.rename(['datetime','quotes'])
```

I want to regress column3 on column 1 and 2 such that the result is for each time like the below code. What is the efficient implementation using scikit-learn?

```python
df4 = panel.groupby('datetime').LinearRegression().fit(X,y)
```